# Can I create master/details view with grid/grid controls?

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

Writing an app for semi-heavy data entry.  I have a list of features entities and each feature owns a list of points.  The feature has 4-5 attributes and each child will have 4-5 attributes.  The user wants the feature info to be visible while the point data is being entered.  Also need to add features/add points.

I'm a wua newbie wondering if I can use the "master/details view" where both my controls are grids?  Can anyone recommend anything better/easier?  This is a 10" tablet app, so I have a reasonable amount of real estate.

Any advice appreciated!  I have found some master/details view tutorials but nothing with grids.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not with Grids: Xaml Grids are layout controls rather than data controls.

You can set up a master detail binding between two data controls, and you can template ListView controls to appear grid-like with each item as a row.